# Should animations in the open source WebM format be allowable on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, imgur

Prior to posting this I searched meta.stackexchange for existing posts on this subject and didn't find any, so...

Image files (both still and animated) used in questions and answers on Stack Exchange sites are generously hosted on Imgur.  Since its inception as primarily text-based, [Stack Exchange has expanded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Site_creation_process) to cover several graphic-heavy subjects/sites.  However, the only format for animated graphics allowed is still GIF.  Useful as they've been, they are currently far more resource-intensive than some later formats.

[WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) is an open-source animated format that's been in use for over ten years now, and has gained widespread acceptance in most browsers.  It's significantly less resource-intensive than animated GIF images.  **[Imgur not only allows it; since 2014 it's preferred it over animated GIF images.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur#GIFV)**  Should animations in WebM format be allowed on Stack Exchange sites?

This is not intended to suggest that Stack Exchange should add any sort of sound feature, and there are several standard practices websites can use to prevent audio.  This question is about the possibility of including WebM as a **visual** file format allowable on Stack Exchange sites in addition to animated GIF images.

Comment: I think my immediate concern is that GIFs are image-only and WebMs (apparently) allow audio, which would be horrible.

Comment: I usually keep my computer muted, so although I agree that audio usage is a concern, I don't think it outweighs the advantages WebM allows.  Especially since I am NOT proposing an expansion of the 2meg file limit, which should provide some discouragement to adding bulky audio data.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to assume most Stack Exchange users are going to have their computer muted. SE would need to prevent autoplay on their end. People didn't want autoplaying video in ads, they won't want it in the Q&A either.

Comment: From what I'm seeing on WebM's Wikipedia article audio in WebM files is handled separately from video.  When I'm making a WebM animation in Blender I have the option to use "no audio" codec.  Can StackExchange allow only WebM files without audio?  However, although I see no usefulness to allowing audio files as audio files, as an animation format the clear improved utility to users along with potentially lighter load on imgur makes the WebM format a valid consideration regardless of audio issues.

Comment: Catija, BSMP, I've edited my question to address your concerns, thx for your help!

Comment: WebMs don't need to use audio. 4chan for example added audioless WebM support a few years ago. With that said, I think there are very few situations where we'd need to embed an animated image but can't use GIFs. APNG, on the other hand, I could see being used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so. While WebM doesn't necessary *require* the use of audio and a website can allow only silent WebMs, there really isn't any need to use them. GIFs are fine for simple animations, and Stack Exchange is not a place that is likely to ever require *video* embedding (yes, it may be used in place of GIFs, but it's still video). Now, APNG support I could see, because it is supported by all major browsers and is vastly superior to GIF, while not having all the overhead of a video codec.

Comment: Imgur is SE's image host, in 2014 Imgur recommended WebM as a replacement for animated gifs - aside from that, I have no preference for WebM or any video format.  But what's your take on WebP?  Also open-source, an image format (not video) that does animated, and GIMP can make WebP animations out-of-the-box (APNG requires a plug-in that I can't make work, GIMP considers APNG a deprecated format).

Comment: @KickAir8p I don't know much about WebP. The issue I have with it is that it uses the V8 video format, and I'm not a fan of having browsers casually playing such complicated formats for security reasons (animated GIF and even APNG is _far_ simpler than V8). Same with formats like AVIF.